# Why variable is not defined in created() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got code like this. I would like to split *deals* array into 3 separate arrays: *dealsCol1*, *dealsCol2*, *dealsCol2* and I would like to have it done after the object is created. I'm a beginner in JavaScript. I previously programmed in C++ and the thing that I guess I need is something like a constructor. I've found out that *created()* function works as a constructor (it's called on object creation). I put the part of the code that splits the array in that function, but I get an error:

> vue.esm.js:591 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: deals is not defined"

I have no idea why it's not defined there, because I guess that it should be. Could you give me some hints how can I solve the problem?

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    deals: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dealsCol1: [],
      dealsCol2: [],
      dealsCol3: []
    };
  },
  created() { // why it doesn't work??
      this.dealsCol1 = this.deals.slice(0, this.deals.length/3),
      this.dealsCol2 = this.deals.slice(this.deals.length/3, 2*this.deals.length/3),
      this.dealsCol3 = this.deals.slice(2*this.deals.length/3, this.deals.length-1) 
  }
};
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

If I use the trick with computed() from one of the answers everything works good. But I'm wondering why the *deals* are visible in every other method beyond constructed(). It is also visible in the template part. Why is that?
The parent component code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <editDealsModal ref="editDealsModal" :deals="deals" @editDeals="editDeals" />
    <table class="table table-sm color mb-2">
      <caption class="caption table-caption">Users</caption>
      <thead>
        <th class="text-left text-nowrap">Deals</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="user in users" :key=user.Id v-bind:class="[{ disabled: user.IsEnabled == false }]">
          <td class="text-left align-middle">{{user.Username}}</td>
          <td class="text-left align-middle">
            <div v-for="role in user.Roles" :key=role>{{role}}</div>
          </td>
          <td class="text-left align-middle">
            <div v-for="deal in user.Deals" :key=deal>{{deal}}</div>
          </td>
          <td class="align-middle">
            <b-btn variant="link" @click="showEditDealsModal(user)" v-bind:disabled="!user.IsEnabled">Edit deals</b-btn>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../../services/HttpRequestService'
import EditDealsModal from './EditDealsModal'

export default {
  props: {
    users: Array,
    deals: Array
  },
  methods: {
    showEditDealsModal(user) {
      this.$refs.editDealsModal.showModal(user, user.Deals || [])
    },
    async editDeals(user, data) {
      try {
        await service.editDeals(user.Id, data);
        this.$emit("userEdited", { type: "success", msg: "Updated deals for " + user.Username })
      } catch (err) {
        this.$emit("userEdited", { type: "danger", msg: "Failed to edit deals for " + user.Username })
      }
    },
  },
  components: {
    EditDealsModal
  }
}
</script>
    enter code here
```

Comment: _ReferenceError: deals is not defined_ i don't see anywhere.

Comment: What is deals ?

Comment: @Jérôme i'm sorry, it should be myData (I needed to edit the code a little and I forgotten about changing the error message)

Comment: @Jai  i'm sorry, it should be myData (I needed to edit the code a little and I forgotten about changing the error message)

Comment: Can you add the code where you pass the prop myData to the child component?

Comment: @coud28098I have added, please take a look at it

Comment: I didn't understand what is wrong

Comment: @jerome In the code above, in constructed method, the deals variable is empty, whereas in every other function and in template part it is not. I guess that it should have some values in the constructed method - that's the problem.

Comment: what do you call "construct" method ? Do you mean `created` ?

Comment: Yes, I meant "created". Sorry, but I haven't get used to keywords in JS and they're still confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to defined a default value for your `myData` array, like this

```
props: {
  myData: {
    default: [],
    type: Array,
  },
},
```

By the way props are used to pass data from parent to child, I don't think this is the best way to do this.

Comment: It helped, but not at all. I got rid of the error, but myData is empty in created() method. When I refer to it in any other method it is not empty. Do you have any idea what might be a problem?

Comment: You need to pass data inside your ‘myData’ array from your parent component. Can you add you parent component code where you add data to your myData props

Comment: I have added, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

myDataCol1,2,3 should be computed properties :

```
props: {
  myData: {
    default: [],
    type: Array,
  },
},
computed: {
  myDataCol1(){
    return this.myData.slice(0, this.myData.length/3)
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```